# how to change 100 .txt file to .log file?

Tags: shell, ksh

I want to change 100 .txt files to .log files. I have the following process, but it is not working.

```
ls |grep *.txt |while read a ; 
do b = 'echo $a |cut d"." -$f1'; 
c=$b ;
mv $a $c; 
done
```

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 4):

```
for i in *.txt; do mv $i $(basename -s '.txt' $i).log; done
```

Or, even simpler, if your system has the `rename` command:

```
rename 's/\.txt$/.log/' *.txt
```

Comment: I don't have rename but the first command gave me this:basename -s .txt $i.log

Comment: `$( ... )` is preferable to backticks in any shell, both for readability and for ease of nesting.

Comment: @user2370590 Did that do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in *.txt
 do
   mv $i ${i%.*}.log
 done
```

${var%"pattern"} take the content of the variable from the start until de last pattern corresponding (from the end) (excluded). So ".*" cut the .txt in this case.